# Neo4J Cypher: Ensuring constraints exist (avoiding errors if they already do)

Tags: neo4j, cypher

On app startup I'd like to ensure indicies and constraints exist.

When I call the following on app startup, I'm receiving an error as the constraint already exists:

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (node:MyLabel) ASSERT node.myProperty IS UNIQUE
```

I'd like to *ensure* that the constraint exists without throwing errors.

Is there a way to do this in Cypher? I'm struggling to find any help in the Neo4J documentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately there isn't good support for this in Cypher, and even the APOC offering here isn't going to be a good fit due to the side-effect of dropping the non-asserted indexes and constraints.

You'll have to make due with string parsing the results of `call db.constraints()` and `call db.indexes()`.

UPDATE

In the latest versions of Neo4j (unsure at what point this was changed) it shouldn't throw any errors if attempting to apply a constraint that already exists.

Also, newer versions of APOC have a new `dropExisting` parameter which allows you to control whether existing schema is dropped or retained prior to applying the new indexes/constraints.

Comment: In 3.5 it wasn't throwing an error but now in 4.0 it does again. Any idea how to do it in 4.0 properly?

Comment: That was an oversight, we had planned 'IF NOT EXISTS` as an option, but that didn't make the earlier releases. Please see our docs for how to use this. https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/administration/indexes-for-search-performance/#administration-indexes-create-a-single-property-index-only-if-it-does-not-already-exist

Answer (score 3):

You could use the APOC Schema assert procedure to create your indexes and constraints. The result will be the net set of indexes/constraints specified in the `indexLabel` and `constraintLabel` collections.

```
CALL apoc.schema.assert({},{MyLabel:['myProperty']}) 
yield label, key, unique, action
RETURN *
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Dave - at present I'm looking for a simpler solution that doesn't involve adding extra plugins into the Neo4J instance I'm using. I will reluctantly surround my CREATE CONSTRAINT statements in try-catch blocks.

Comment: Careful with this one, as I recall `apoc.schema.assert()` drops all constraints/indexes that aren't asserted.

Comment: Agree. First time i ran it i deleted all of my unasserted constraints. It would be nice it it just has a 'test' mode.

Answer (score 1):

You can use IF NOT EXISTS, for example: CREATE CONSTRAINT IF NOT EXISTS ON (node:MyLabel) ASSERT node.myProperty IS UNIQUE